# How to assign $_post array of array to variables to insert in DB

Tags: php

I am passing arrays to $_Post and on the following page, I would like to assign the values of each _Post array index so I could then insert in a table in my database.

here is what I have when I print $_Post

```
Array
(

[id_client] => Array
        (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

[id_participant] => Array
    (
        [0] => 44
        [1] => 48
        [2] => 50
    )

[session] => Array
    (
         [0] => 1
         [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )
)
```

so I would like to be able to assign those to variables on each loop:

```
$client = id_client[0]
$participant = id_participant[0]
$session = session[0]
```

so then I could insert them in my database and move on to index 1, 2 ,3 ...

Comment: What's the specific question? Show the code that's not working with an explanation of what is happening with it, what you're getting, vs what you're expecting.

Comment: There is no code not working, I am asking how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have corresponding sets of data in each of the child arrays, just iterate one of them and use the key to access the others.

```
foreach ($_POST['id_client'] as $key => $client) {
    $participant = $_POST['id_participant'][$key];
    $session = $_POST['id_session'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if one of the arrays is longer?  This is what I asked myself, the other answer is perfectly acceptable if they will always be the same length.  But I thought I would whip one up that accounts for that.

Plus it gave me an excuse to use `$$` variable variable and `??` null coalesce...

If it is possible that they could be different lengths then you might want to do something like this:

```
$array = [
    'id_client' => [1,1,1],
    'id_participant' => [44,48,50],
    'session' =>[1,2,3,4] //< added a fourth item
 ];

//count the number of nested items
$a = array_map(function($item){
    return count($item);
}, $array);

//get the max number of nested items
$max = max($a);

//iterate up to the $max number of times
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $$key =   $value[$i] ?? false; //$$ is a variable variable, ?? is PHP7+ only
    }
    //these exist because of $$key, its magic
    echo $id_client ."\n";
    echo $id_participant ."\n";
    echo $session ."\n";
    echo "-----------------\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
44
1
-----------------
1
48
2
-----------------
1
50
3
-----------------
false
false
4
-----------------
```

You can try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/700b315025df49bf1609b1a27d79284388f0b867)

Comment: I will keep that in mind for further use but, in this case, there is always the arrays will always have the same lenght, Client and participant are hidden values in the form and session is a select box which has a default value.

Comment: Kool, happy coding!  The first time I saw `$$` in code probably in `2009` I thought it was a typo, but i was noob back then.... lol  ... I was fixing this site written for PHP4 something so it would work in PHP5.3

Comment: The use of variable variables should be discouraged.  While they are a legitimate part of php, variable variables are usually a symptom of suboptimal array data storage.  When you think variable variables are the solution, think longer and harder about what you are trying to do.  (this comment is not aimed at Artistic as much as it is a warning to future researchers.)